# How to remove transparency here

Tags: javascript, three.js

[image: Rendered output]

How to i remove the clipped objects that have become transparent or prevent the object below it from being shown.
It would be better if it looks like a real world solid cubes.
This is written in javascript with three.js. HTML and CSS have no faults. Only the rendering shows issue here.

```js
var scene, camera, renderer, cube;

var WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
var HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;

var SPEED = 0.001;

function init() {
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    initLight();
    drawScene();
    initCamera();
    initRenderer();
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
}

function initLight() {
    const light = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF);
    light.position.x = 50;
    light.position.y = 50;
    light.position.z = 130;
    scene.add(light);
}

function initCamera() {
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, WIDTH / HEIGHT, 1, 10);
    camera.position.set(1, 3, 5);
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);
}

function initRenderer() {
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
    renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    renderer.sortObjects = false;
}

function drawScene() {
    var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0xFF6600 });
    var shape = new THREE.CubeGeometry(1, 1, 1);
    cube = new THREE.Group();
    for (var a = -10; a <= 10; a = a + 2) {
        for (var b = -10; b <= 10; b = b + 2) {
            for (var c = -10; c <= 10; c = c + 2) {
                var part = new THREE.Mesh(shape, material);
                part.position.set(a, b, c);
                cube.add(part);
            }
        }
    }
    scene.add(cube);
}
function rotateCube() {
    cube.rotation.x -= SPEED;
    cube.rotation.y -= SPEED;
    cube.rotation.z -= SPEED;
}

function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    rotateCube();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

init();
render();
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the PerspectiveCamera near plane closer, to 0.01 instead of 1, and added the includes to make your snippet run.

The "transparency" you're seeing are the cubes clipping against the camera near plane. By pulling the plane closer to the camera, you're making the viewport smaller in the world, so it more easily fits in between the cubes.

Another thing is backface culling.. that makes cubes invisible if they are viewed from inside. You can disable backface culling via material.side = THREE.DoubleSide, at the cost of potentially rendering twice as much geometry.

```js
var scene, camera, renderer, cube;

var WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
var HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;

var SPEED = 0.001;

function init() {
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    initLight();
    drawScene();
    initCamera();
    initRenderer();
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
}

function initLight() {
    const light = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF);
    light.position.x = 50;
    light.position.y = 50;
    light.position.z = 130;
    scene.add(light);
}

function initCamera() {
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, WIDTH / HEIGHT, 0.01, 10);
    camera.position.set(1, 3, 5);
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);
}

function initRenderer() {
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
    renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    renderer.sortObjects = false;
}

function drawScene() {
    var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0xFF6600, side: THREE.DoubleSide});
    var shape = new THREE.CubeGeometry(1, 1, 1);
    cube = new THREE.Group();
    for (var a = -10; a <= 10; a = a + 2) {
        for (var b = -10; b <= 10; b = b + 2) {
            for (var c = -10; c <= 10; c = c + 2) {
                var part = new THREE.Mesh(shape, material);
                part.position.set(a, b, c);
                cube.add(part);
            }
        }
    }
    scene.add(cube);
}
function rotateCube() {
    cube.rotation.x -= SPEED;
    cube.rotation.y -= SPEED;
    cube.rotation.z -= SPEED;
}

function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    rotateCube();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

init();
render();
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Comment: An important distinction is that you don't need to be _inside_ a shape for backface culling to take effect. Backface culling occurs when a face (triangle) is viewed from the opposite direction of the face normal (its "back"). In the case of a cube, the backs of the faces point to the inside of the cube. When the close cubes clip the camera's near plane, exposing their inside faces, those inside faces don't render because of backface culling, allowing you to see the cubes behind them.

Comment: camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, WIDTH / HEIGHT, 0.01, 10);camera.position.set(1, 1, 1); 
These lines helped fix the issue
Thanks a lot